# How to calculate the time for which the serial port message was sent

Tags: vb.net, listview, timer, serial-port

I'm receiving a message from Serial-Port, each message sends from microcontroller with diffrent delays, two of them send with 10ms delay, one 50ms and another 100ms. What i'm trying it's calculate that delay for each message and display it on listview1. What i tried so far it's create timer2 with interval = 1 and it's increasing VAR by 1 everytime the timer elapsed

```
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
      Timer2.Tick
      timer_count = timer_count + 1
    End Sub
```

Then when we recevied message from serial we put "timer_count" into **listview**

```
 Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(can_id)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(dlc)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(data)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(timer_count)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(count)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(asciival)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
```

then when we updating subitems of listview, we substract previous timer_count value from current timer_count.

```
   Dim founditem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(articlecheck)

   If Not (founditem Is Nothing) Then
          founditem.SubItems(0).Text = can_id
          founditem.SubItems(3).Text = timer_count - founditem.SubItems(3).Text
```

The problem is that it doesnt work, value in **subitem(3)** is always increasing. Any tips or ideas? Thanks in further

Comment: You are trying to make mathematical operation with text (see last code line)!

Comment: yes, but founditem.SubItems(3).Text always contains only numbers

Comment: Does the property contain numbers or *text with numeric characters*? See `Text` property data type.

Comment: AS i understand i have to do math operations with VARs that doesnt have string property? Or convert string to number?

Comment: You need to cast values to a [numeric type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types) before evaluate math expression.  Try to use `CInt` or `CDbl` function in dependence of `timer_count` type. See [Type conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions) for details.